# Usage of definite article with nationalities

Tags: word-usage, definite-articles

> Bering's men found Eskimos in Alaska.

or

> Bering's men found the Eskimos in Alaska.

Which is right?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. "Which is right" answers almost always depend on what meaning is intended— either can be right in certain circumstances, either may be wrong in other circumstances. What is the context? For additional guidance, please take the site [tour] and review the [help]. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

"Bering's men found Eskimos in Alaska" implies that Eskimos were already known to live in other regions.

"Bering's men found the Eskimos in Alaska" implies either that that's the only region where they live, or more generally that Bering's men found those Eskimos living in Alaska as opposed to elsewhere, or even that these particular Eskimos have already been referred to in the narrative.